# How many equivalence classes does the following equivalence relation have?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

> Let $S \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$, and define a relation $R$ on $S \times S$ by
>
> $$(m, n)R(s, t) \quad \text{ if and only if } \quad m + n = s + t$$
>
> Consider the set $S = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$. How many equivalence
>   classes does $R$ have? Describe the equivalence classes of $R$
>   without explicitly listing the partition of $S × S$.

My try:
I have proved that the relation is an equivalence relation, $R$ is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive. For the set $S$ there are $2^6$ subsets.
Any help starting this problem would be appreciated!

Comment: Anyone who’s played a game with dice (e.g. Monopoly) for some time, knows that every roll from $2$ to $12$ can be made with a pair of dice...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two elements $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ in $S \times S$ are related if $a+b=c+d$. For example, if we take the element $(1,5) \in S \times S$, then $(1,5) \sim (1,5)$ because $1+5=1+5=6$.

So for **finding the equivalence class** of $(1,5)$ we ask ourselves: what are all other elements $(c,d) \in S \times S$ such that $(1,5) \sim (c,d)$?

For that, we want $c+d=6$. So look for all the pairs that satisfy this condition.
$$[(1,5)]=\{(1,5), (5,1), (3,3), (2,4), (4,2)\}.$$
Likewise
$$[(1,1)]=\{(1,1)\} \qquad \text{and} \qquad [(5,6)]=\{(5,6), (6,5)\}.$$

Hopefully you can proceed from here to get the remaining equivalence classes.

**Note:** If you just want the number of equivalence classes (without describing them), then note that each equivalence class can be associated with the **sum** of the pairs in that, e.g. the class $[(1,5)]$ can be associated to the **sum** $6$ and class $[(1,1)]$ can be associated with the **sum** $2$ and so on. So the number of distinct classes is the number of distinct **sums**.

Comment: So for example [(1,5)] and [(5,1)] will have the same elements, so overall I have the sum of 2,3,4,...,11 , hence 10 equivalence classes ?

Comment: @HHH You remembered to include $(1,1)$ but you forgot about $(6,6)$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

In general if $f:X\to Y$ is some function then the relation $\sim$ on $X$ defined by $a\sim b\iff f(a)=f(b)$ is an equivalence relation.

The equivalence class represented by $x\in X$ is the set $\{a\in X\mid f(a)=f(x)\}$ and there is a one-to-one relation between equivalence classes and elements of the image of $f$.

So the number of equivalence classes equals the cardinality of the image of $f$.

---

You can apply that here.

Note that $(m,n)R(s,t)\iff f(m,n)=f(s,t)$ where function $f:S\times S\to\mathbb Z$ is prescribed by $(m,n)\to m+n$.

You only have to find the cardinality of the set $\{m+n\mid m,n\in S\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's describe the equivalence classes.
Every class has a feature that every pair in this class has the same sum. 
The minimum sum is 2 (from (1,1)), ant the max is 12 (from (6,6)).
It's easy to see, the we will also have all the numbers in a range [2,12].
That means, that you have 11 classes.